# Writing a function to handle exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Is it reasonable to think I can write a void function to take in an Exception and output the stuff that a catch block normally would? Here's an example of my exception catcher (which I would make individual ones for common exceptions I handle):

```
private void exCatch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR - " + blah blah blah + ex.ToString(), blah blah);
}
```

Here it is in practice:

```
try
{
    stuff
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    exCatch(e);
}
```

Is this an efficient way to handle exceptions? If this is reasonable, do people do this? It seems like it could speed up your coding not having to copy paste all your exception junk over and over. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `ex.StackTrace` is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: There are a few Modules that can do some exception logging too.  Depending on what you want for your routine, it might be worth looking into some of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with that at all. In fact, adding functions to reduce code repetition is definitely advisable. Then if you want to change say the MessageBox buttons you change it once and you're done everywhere.

One note is that you should consider only catching certain types of exceptions that you're expecting. If you're catching an exception it should be because you know where it came from and exactly what to do with it. Or else you might be catching something that should be handled at a higher level and your app can get into an invalid state. Here's an example.

ArgumentNullException

FormatException

OverflowException

Are the exceptions that Int32.Parse(string) throws. Lets say you know you wont be passing in Null this is how MSDN shows you should handle the function:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       string[] values = { "+13230", "-0", "1,390,146", "$190,235,421,127",
                      "0xFA1B", "163042", "-10", "007", "2147483647", 
                      "2147483648", "16e07", "134985.0", "-12034",
                      "-2147483648", "-2147483649" };
  foreach (string value in values)
  {
     try {
        int number = Int32.Parse(value); 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, number);
     }
     catch (FormatException) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Bad Format", value);
     }   
     catch (OverflowException) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Overflow", value);   
     }  
       }
    }
 }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

Always look up the exceptions that a method can throw and always document those that you are catching and throwing in your methods.